# Accessing custom properties of extended control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am having a really hard time finding the right resources for this and thought maybe someone on StackOverflow would know this. I am extending a PictureBox Control in a Windows Forms application and I have done this *exact* same thing in the past but unfortunately, I do not remember how I got it to work the way I want it to.

My control code, is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SomeApplication
{
    public class Picture : PictureBox
    {
        public static Bitmap Thumbnail { get; set; }
        public static Bitmap OriginalPhoto { get; set; }
        public static string Name { get; set; }
        public static Int64 Order { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What I [have done in the past, and] would like to do now is access these properties once I have created a Picture control and added it to the form.

```
private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Controls.Add(new Picture() { Order = 7, Location = new Point(0, 0) });
}
```

But that does not work. I cannot access any of these custom properties from picture1. I can only access them from the actual *type* itself, like this:

```
Picture.Order = 8;
```

which is useless.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the `static` from the property definitions. This causes the properties to be on the class instead of the instance.

```
public class Picture : PictureBox
{
    public Bitmap Thumbnail { get; set; }
    public Bitmap OriginalPhoto { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Int64 Order { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** You declared your properties as `staic`. static memeners belong to class level but not instance level hence you can not initialise them from the oject initializers.

**Solution :** You need to make your properties `non-static` by removing the `static` keyword infront of the properties.

Try This:

```
public Bitmap Thumbnail { get; set; }
public Bitmap OriginalPhoto { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public Int64 Order { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you again for your help @Sudhakar. I will up-vote your answer when I have enough reputation to do so. I think I should accept Patrick's answer though, since both answers are the same except his was first according to S.O.

Comment: @spike.y:  You are Welcome :) Glad tobe help of you,